# unable to return values for new column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, return

I'm trying to add an additional column to my dataframe. I use `if/else` condition based on other variables `var1` and `var2`, and try to `return` values into this new column `prediction`. By using the following codes, I am able to create a column name, but the new column is EMPTY for some reason I can't figure out. There's no error presents, so I assume there's something wrong in `return`? Thanks for your help!

Here is a subset of my dataframe and codes:

```
var1    var2    choice    prediction
-1.7     0       TRUE     
3.5      0       TRUE
1.2      0       FALSE      #empty#   
6.7      0       FALSE
-0.6     1       TRUE
-2.8     1       FALSE
2.1      1       TRUE

def prediction(row):
    if row['var1'] > row['var2']:
        if row['choice'] == "TRUE": # "TRUE" and "FALSE" are bool.
            return 'miss'   # return values and add into the new column
        elif row['choice'] == "FALSE":
            return 'match'

    elif row['var1'] < row['var2']:
        if row['choice'] == "FALSE":
            return 'miss'
        elif row['choice'] == "TRUE":
            return 'match'

    else:
        if row['choice'] == "TRUE":
            return 'match'
        elif row['choice'] == "FALSE":
            return 'miss' 

df['prediction'] = df.apply(lambda row: prediction(row), axis=1)
```

Comment: Values are strings `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'` or boolean `True` and `False` ?

Comment: What is `df.dtypes` ?

Comment: @jezrael Sorry that I was not clear. No, they are strings. Not sure what you mean by `df.dtypes`, but `df` means my dataframe's name

Comment: What is `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is problem your data are boolean, no string `TRUE` and `FALSE`, so inner conditions never return `True`:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1':np.random.randint(10, size=N),
                   'var2':np.random.randint(10, size=N), 
                   'choice':np.random.choice([True, False], size=N)})
print (df)
   choice  var1  var2
0   False     2     9
1   False     2     0
2    True     6     0
3    True     1     9
4   False     3     3
5    True     9     4
6    True     6     0
7   False     1     0
8    True     0     4
9   False     1     1

print (df.dtypes)
choice     bool
var1      int32
var2      int32
dtype: object
```

---

```
def prediction(row):
    if row['var1'] > row['var2']:
        if row['choice'] == "TRUE":
            return 'miss'   # return values and add into the new column
        elif row['choice'] == "FALSE":
            return 'match'

    elif row['var1'] < row['var2']:
        if row['choice'] == "FALSE":
            return 'miss'
        elif row['choice'] == "TRUE":
            return 'match'

    else:
        if row['choice'] == "TRUE":
            return 'match'
        elif row['choice'] == "FALSE":
            return 'miss' 

df['prediction'] = df.apply(lambda row: prediction(row), axis=1)
print (df)
   choice  var1  var2 prediction
0   False     2     9       None
1   False     2     0       None
2    True     6     0       None
3    True     1     9       None
4   False     3     3       None
5    True     9     4       None
6    True     6     0       None
7   False     1     0       None
8    True     0     4       None
9   False     1     1       None
```

So need:

```
def prediction(row):
    if row['var1'] > row['var2']:
        if row['choice'] == True:
            return 'miss'   # return values and add into the new column
        elif row['choice'] == False:
            return 'match'

    elif row['var1'] < row['var2']:
        if row['choice'] == False:
            return 'miss'
        elif row['choice'] == True:
            return 'match'

    else:
        if row['choice'] == True:
            return 'match'
        elif row['choice'] == False:
            return 'miss' 

df['prediction'] = df.apply(lambda row: prediction(row), axis=1)
print (df)
   choice  var1  var2 prediction
0   False     2     9       miss
1   False     2     0      match
2    True     6     0       miss
3    True     1     9      match
4   False     3     3       miss
5    True     9     4       miss
6    True     6     0       miss
7   False     1     0      match
8    True     0     4      match
9   False     1     1       miss
```

Another possible problem is if values not match - string `'True'` with `'TRUE'` and similar with `False`:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1':np.random.randint(10, size=N),
                   'var2':np.random.randint(10, size=N), 
                   'choice':np.random.choice(['True', 'False'], size=N)})
print (df)
  choice  var1  var2
0  False     2     9
1  False     2     0
2   True     6     0
3   True     1     9
4  False     3     3
5   True     9     4
6   True     6     0
7  False     1     0
8   True     0     4
9  False     1     1
```

---

```
def prediction(row):
    if row['var1'] > row['var2']:
        if row['choice'] == "TRUE":
            return 'miss'   # return values and add into the new column
        elif row['choice'] == "FALSE":
            return 'match'

    elif row['var1'] < row['var2']:
        if row['choice'] == "FALSE":
            return 'miss'
        elif row['choice'] == "TRUE":
            return 'match'

    else:
        if row['choice'] == "TRUE":
            return 'match'
        elif row['choice'] == "FALSE":
            return 'miss' 

df['prediction'] = df.apply(lambda row: prediction(row), axis=1)
print (df)
  choice  var1  var2 prediction
0  False     2     9       None
1  False     2     0       None
2   True     6     0       None
3   True     1     9       None
4  False     3     3       None
5   True     9     4       None
6   True     6     0       None
7  False     1     0       None
8   True     0     4       None
9  False     1     1       None
```

Comment: AMAZING! Thanks for your detail explanation with examples! My bad, `TRUE` and `FALSE` are bool. I tracked down the wrong variable.

Comment: You too! Thanks again, l'm happy that I learnt a new "debug" code `print (df.dtypes)`, pretty sure I will use it a lot later on since it's hard to remember every variables' type.